# MacOS XAMPP Access Forbidden Error 403 - You don't have permission to access the requested directory

Tags: php, macos, apache, xampp, virtualhost

I have some PHP web apps running off XAMPP 7.4.1 on macOS 10.15. XAMPP has worked for me in the past. I got my dev environment screwed up because 32 bit apps sh*t the bed with Catalina, and my old XAMPP installation didn't open. I got my VirtualHosts set back up, but now when I try to access one of my sites I get the following error.

```
Access forbidden!
You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is 
either no index document or the directory is read-protected.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 403
```

My virtual hosts look like the following:

```
# localhost
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs"
    <Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes execCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

#####################
# PERSONAL PROJECTS #
#####################

# Dunsparce.net
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dunsparce.net
    DocumentRoot "/Users/danielschnoll/Documents/Projects/Dunsparce.net"
    <Directory "/Users/danielschnoll/Documents/Projects/Dunsparce.net">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog "logs/dunsparce-error_log"
</VirtualHost>
```

I have more VirtualHosts listed and they all follow the same format. I have `Require all granted` on each one, as well as the `Allow Override All` and the `Options...` line. Like I said at the start of the post, they all worked in the past. I also have the `# Include` uncommented in my `httpd.conf` file, though I'm pretty sure Access Forbidden error is completely unrelated to it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try this. Check permissions on the `htdocs` folder. Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22951499/mac-os-x-xampp-access-forbidden

Comment: @TPHughes has nothing to do with `htdocs`, I don't have any projects stored there. The only thing that is at `htdocs` is the landing dashboard for `localhost`, which loads just fine. Everything else has "permissions denied"

Comment: If the localhost landing page has incorrect permissions it can cause it. But if not then it is fine. Prune through the rest of the comments on there, there are more suggestions.Ensure apache is restarted after each change.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I wound up having to edit `httpd.conf` again. There’s a section for `User` group permissions. By default it says

```
User daemon
Group daemon
```

Change the `User` from `daemon` to your macOS Username. For me, my `User` group now looks like

```
User danielschnoll
Group daemon
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Now to solve the default localhost site showing up :)

Comment: still working in 2023.

Answer (score 3):

If you landed here after an Upgrade to MAC OS my problem was solved when I moved the web files out of the `/Documents/` folder.

Answer (score 2):

Follow below *steps*:

- Go to `htdocs` folder
- Right click on the folder and get info
- Go to **Sharing & Permissions:** and  >>> add your user
- Your user : read & write

Comment: thanks, it's works and simple solution. in my case i need to add read & write for everyone, only for mac user is not working.

Answer (score 1):

How to Fix XAMPP Error 403

**Step 1: Open the Volumes tab in the XAMPP app**

First, open the XAMPP app on your Mac and navigate into the Volumes tab

**Step 2: Click on 'Mount'**

Next, you're going to mount the opt/lampp directory onto your computer.

**Step 3: Click on 'Explore'**

**Step 4: Open the 'etc' folder**

By clicking on explore your app should have opened the lampp directory. In it you'll see many folders and files. Click on the one named 'etc'.

**Step 5: Open the 'extra' folder**

**Step 6: Open the 'httpd-xampp.conf' file**

**Step 7: Find the AuthConfig requirements code**

Search for 'phpmyadmin' in the httpd-xampp.conf code and find the following section:

httpd-xampp phpmyadmin require local

**Step 8: Change 'Require local' to 'Require all granted'**

This is the step that will fix the 403 error. Change the line of code to replace 'Require local' with 'Require all granted'. Then save your file.

**Step 9: Restart all services**

Navigate back to the XAMPP app and click on 'Services', then 'Restart all'. This will restart all of the services. You'll notice the status lights turn yellow and eventually return back to green.

**Step 10: Refresh the phpMyAdmin page**

The last step is to refresh the phpMyAdmin page you had open earlier.

If you closed it, no problem, just return to the General tab on your XAMPP app and click 'Go to Application'. That will open the dashboard in your browser where you can again navigate to the phpMyAdmin page.

Answer (score 1):

Only one solution worked for me.

Go to the file `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/httpd.conf`, edit the part:

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied 
</Directory>
```

To:

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And don't forget to restart the `Apache Web Server` from the application.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the  User group permissions didn't work for me, but creating a Symbolic link to my working directory worked:

```
cd /opt/lampp/htdocs
ln -s /home/user/Projects/www www
```

Then in /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf

```
DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/www"
```