# How to change xampp htdocs directory in Mac OS Big Sur

Tags: php, macos, apache, xampp

I have installed Xampp 7.2.34 from [https://www.apachefriends.org](https://www.apachefriends.org/xampp-files/7.2.34/xampp-osx-7.2.34-0-installer.dmg) in Big Sur.
XAMPP htdocs folder is placed in `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles` directory. Is there anyway that I can change the location of htdocs folder and place all my projects in the new location.

***Current Location:*** `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs`

***Desired Location:*** `/Users/user/Desktop/Work/PHP/htdocs`

I am following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8060533/how-to-change-xampp-htdocs-directory-in-osx) question in Stackoverflow but it seems quite old and I was not able to accomplish what I required.

***Already done:***

1. Created new empty htdocs folder on desired location
2. Changed `User daemon` to `User user` in `xamppfiles/etc/httpd.conf`
3. Didn't change `Group daemon`
4. Changed `DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs"` to `DocumentRoot "/Users/user/Desktop/Work/PHP/htdocs"` in `xamppfiles/etc/httpd.conf`
5. Changed `<Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs">` to `<Directory "/Users/user/Desktop/Work/PHP/htdocs">` in `xamppfiles/etc/httpd.conf`
6. I also uncommented this line of code `Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` in `xamppfiles/etc/httpd.conf`

***Result:***

`Access forbidden!` error.

[image]

What did I miss? Has something changed in these years? TIA.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, but worked with this this solution. You could using Xampp in another version, [Xampp 7.4.15](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Mac%20OS%20X/7.4.15/) with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60052142/macos-xampp-access-forbidden-error-403-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-the) configuration

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me using XAMPP 8.2.0 and macOS 12.6.2 Monterrey:

Make a copy of htdocs and put it where you want it. In my case, I made my copy in /Users/me/Dropbox/XAMPP/htdocs

- Edit /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/httpd.conf
- Change
  DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs”
  to
  DocumentRoot "/Users/me/Dropbox/XAMPP/htdocs"
- Change
  <Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs”>
  to
  <Directory "/Users/me/Dropbox/Programming/XAMPP/htdocs">
- Change
  User daemon
  to
  User me (your user name)
- Edit /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
- After
  $cfg['SaveDir'] = '';
  add
  $cfg['TempDir'] = '/tmp';
- Edit /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/properties.ini
- Change
  apache_htdocs_directory=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs
  to
  apache_htdocs_directory=/Users/me/Dropbox/Programming/XAMPP/htdocs

Save the files and restart the servers.

That was it. Hope helps someone. I looked for this answer for a long time.